# Desencriptar. AES. JAVA. Dos errores: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java

Tengo que realizar la encriptacion y desencriptación mediante AES.
El cifrage me da bien, pero es descifraje me da problemas. No hay forma, llevo ya una semanita.

Este es el código:

```
public  class Cifrar {

// Definición del tipo de algoritmo a utilizar (AES, DES, RSA)
private final static String alg = "AES";
private final static int keyLength=128;
private final static int ivLength=128;

// Definición del modo de cifrado a utilizar
private final static String cI =  "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";



// Aqui generamos la clave aleatoria AES
public static byte [] ClaveAleatoria() throws Exception {
        //Generamos la clave aleatoria.
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(alg);
        keyGen.init(keyLength, new SecureRandom());
        SecretKey aesKey = keyGen.generateKey();
        byte[] aesKeyBytes = aesKey.getEncoded();
        return aesKeyBytes;

}



       public static  byte[] VectorInicialAleatorio() throws Exception {   
        byte [] iv = SecureRandom.getSeed(ivLength/8);
        return iv;

     }





public static byte[] encrypt( byte [] aesKeyBytes, byte[]  iv , String cleartext) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cI);
        //SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKeyBytes.getBytes(), alg);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKeyBytes, alg);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        //System.out.println(ivParameterSpec);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(cleartext.getBytes());
        //return new String(encodeBase64(encrypted));
        //return new String(Base64.encode(encrypted));
        return encrypted;
}







     //AQUI ESTA EL PROBLEMAA- PARECE QUE LE FALTAN BYTES

    public static String decrypt(byte [] aesKeyBytes, byte[]  iv, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cI);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKeyBytes, alg);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        //byte[] enc = Base64.encode(encrypted);
        System.out.println(encrypted+"aqui despues viene el fallo");
        //byte[] enc = Base64.decode(encrypted);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        //byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(enc);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return new String(decrypted);
}

 }
```

Este es el main

```
public class main {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

     String cleartext = "hola";

    byte[] textocifrado= 



 crypto.Cifrar.encrypt(crypto.Cifrar.ClaveAleatoria(),crypto.Cifrar.VectorInicialAleatorio(),cleartext);

   System.out.println("Texto encriptado: "+textocifrado);
   System.out.println("Texto desencriptado: "+crypto.Cifrar.decrypt(crypto.Cifrar.ClaveAleatoria(),crypto.Cifrar.VectorInicialAleatorio(),textocifrado));
```

Cuando ejecuto me dice:

```
Texto encriptado: ����ߏ�Ϻ��Qθ�
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
����ߏ�Ϻ��Qθ�aqui despues viene el fallo
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    at crypto.Cifrar.decrypt(Cifrar.java:129)
    at crypto.main.main(main.java:24)
C:\Users\Jurpark\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 1):

**NO** conviertas `byte[]` a `String` a no ser de que estés seguro de que ese `byte[]` se corresponde con un String (por ejemplo, tras desencriptar un valor que originalmente era un `String`).

Un `String` en Java se codifica en UTF-8, lo cual significa que no todos los valores posibles son válidos. Sencillamente, no puedes estar seguro que pasar de `byte[]` a `String` y de vuelta a `byte[]` te devuelva el valor original.

Si el `byte[]` representa el contenido de un `String`, la conversión se puede hacer sin problemas(v.g., si obtienes el `byte[]` de un `String`, la conversión de vuelta a `String` no presenta problemas); al fin y al cabo, ese `byte[]` ya representa al `String` en el formato correcto. Así:

```
new String("hola".getBytes()); // te devuelve un nuevo String con el texto "hola".
```

La cuestión es que **no todos los byte[] representarán `String`s**.

Además, no tiene mucho sentido, ya que un `String` representa un valor de texto mientras que un `byte[]` representa datos binarios.

Solución: No conviertas; trabaja con los `byte[]` directamente.

Una vez aclarado este punto, las llamadas que haces a tus métodos son:

```
crypto.Cifrar.encrypt(
    crypto.Cifrar.ClaveAleatoria(),
    crypto.Cifrar.VectorInicialAleatorio(),
    cleartext);

crypto.Cifrar.decrypt(
    crypto.Cifrar.ClaveAleatoria(),
    crypto.Cifrar.VectorInicialAleatorio(),
    textocifrado))
```

Es decir, llamas al método `ClaveAleatoria()`<sup>1</sup> **una vez para cada función**. A no ser que siempre se genere la misma clave (lo dudo mucho), **estás tratando de desencriptar con una clave distinta de la que se usó para encriptar**. Y, precisamente, el objetivo de una función de encriptación es que eso sea imposible.

Guarda la clave que vayas a usar en una variable y pásala a los dos métodos.

---

<sup>1</sup>En Java, los nombres de métodos, variables y atributos **siempre empiezan por minúscula**.

Comment: Hola Juan, el problema es que a veces no se ni lo que hago ni lo que toco. Acabo de poner ahora `return  encrypted ´ y ya me da mal. No se como ponerlo en byte[] . Tambien decir que hay gente que pone Base64.encode(...) . He ido a ver a la profesora y me ha dicho que lo quitara y me ha 'echado' del despacho

Comment: Tienes que cambiar el tipo devuelto por el método a `byte[]` y también la variable donde lo guardas...

Comment: Perfect Juan. Ahora he puesto public static byte[] y return  encrypted. Despues en decrypt (mantengo String) pero donde se le meten las cosas he puesto byte[] encrypted. Peero el main me explota. Ahora el 'hola' que es texto como lo meto?

Comment: Como no seas más específico (mensaje de error, etc.) será muy difícil entenderte.

Comment: Un segundo ahora te lo paso

Comment: En el main ->Tengo: String cleartext = "hola"; /*salto de line*/ String textocifrado= crypto.Cifrar.encrypt(crypto.Cifrar.ClaveAleatoria(),crypto.Cifrar.VectorInicialAleatorio(),cleartext); Y en la bombilla a la izquierda de esta line de codigo me dice : incompatible type: byte[] cannot be converted String. He puesto para solucionar cleartext.getBytes()`pero sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Vale, he quitado el string y he puesto byte[] y ahora da luz amarilla. y todo concuerda, pero me sigue dando el mismo error al ejecutar Given final block not properly padded

Comment: No se si te llegan las notificaciones de mis comentarios @SJuan76

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta para mostrar las modificaciones en tu código

Comment: Hola Juan. Ya he modificado el codigo :)

Comment: Una cosa,al principio me has dicho: "NO conviertas byte[] a String a no ser de que estés seguro de que ese byte[] se corresponde con un String" ; pues yo estoy conviritiendo inicialmente  un String que es Hola. Pero bueno, a ver si consigo ver algun dia: texto desencriptado: Hola

Comment: tengo que poner esto para que te lleguen las notificaciones? @SJuan76

Comment: Las notificaciones llegan. Pero, para que quede claro, **NO** estoy montando guardia para ver si te va bien el programa o no, **NO** estoy las 24 horas delante del ordenador, **NO** me conecto aquí cada vez que estoy delante del ordenador y **NO** tengo obligación de responder a tus preguntas cada vez que estoy aquí. Entiendo que necesitas ayuda (para eso preguntas), y me gusta ayudar en lo que puedo, pero eso no significa que vaya a soportar cualquier comportamiento...

Comment: Disculpa las molestias Juan. Perdona si te he molestado.